# How to i can calclulate in react-native input?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I got an problem to calculate my input in react-native, sorry, im total new in React-native and stack overflow. Correct me if I'm wrong.

[The Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fpN5.png)

[The Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGpzY.png)

Comment: No need for pictures, you can paste the code directly in the question. As for what is going wrong you are using functions that we can't see the definition for.

Answer (score 0):

Add in your TextInput the keyboardType="numeric" parameter, i think the problem is calculate with string not a number look here [textinput](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput)

```
<TextInput
    ...
    keyboardType="numeric"
  />
```